# Notification Layout file

Tags: android, notifications

I want to set the layout for Notification Dynamic, I check some references. It is said to use a Layout file. I do not want to quote Layout file. I want dynamic layout. After I define all controls, I use below sentence to quote:

```
RemoteViews contentView = null;
contentView = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),0000);
```

It is always quote a Layout file in space of”0000”. But this”0000” is an ID of LinearLayout. Now It has the error like this:

```
couldn't inflate view for notification org.MM.MMShow/0x4308f
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

Comment: Please explain your question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are creating a layout dynamically like

```
LinearLayout lLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
bla bla
```

then why you are not add that layout like

```
contentView = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), lLayout);
```

rather using the id of layout.